# SQL Query to delete wordpress post with similar titles

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-delete

I have a wordpress site with many posts and I need a SQL Query to delete a no. of posts with contains same term in the title.

Eg.

```
Post 1: How To Learn HTML.
Post 2: How To Learn CSS.
Post 3: How To Dabble With HTML.
Post 4: Learn HTML in minutes.
```

I want to Delete all posts with the word "HTML" in the Title as here Post 1,3 and 4.

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve with? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from wp_posts
where wp_title like '%HTML%'
```

Comment: This Does Not Work With Wordpress. Are You Familiar With Wordpress

Comment: How does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try following query and comments?

`DELETE FROM table_prefix_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%HTML%'`

*Change *table_prefix* in the query. Default is wp. (eg.: wp_posts)

Comment: Nop Thats Not Working Too

Comment: @AaishaMonishaMalik What error you're getting?